# How to handle / cleanup obsolete aggregated css / js?

Tags: 7, javascript, theming, css-js-aggregation

I'm only using Drupal 7 built in CSS / JS aggregation, however the files folder where the css.gz and js.gz files live are filling up at a fairly rapid pace, and while I'm sure it'll be a while before it starts to totally fill up the drive, nows as good a time as any to get a handle on the situation.

- Current file count in /js is 335
- Current file count in /css is 451

Is there any standard method I should be employing to deal with this situation? I'd prefer a solution that keeps the drupal in the loop.

Additionally, I see that many of the gz files have non-gz counterparts. Is there some reason both .css and .css.gz files are kept? Degredation maybe?

Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm that cron is running?

Comment: It certainly is

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is actually by design so that cached pages with older versions of files don't get broken. See this [closed issue](http://drupal.org/node/1118226#comment-4657112).

TL;DR: They will be deleted automatically 30 days (or whatever your `drupal_stale_file_threshold` variable is set to) after they were created via `drupal_clear_css_cache()` and `drupal_clear_js_cache()`. So the solution is to modify the `drupal_stale_file_threshold` value to something lower than the default 30 days.

- **When are old files deleted**

> Old cache files are not deleted immediately when the lookup variable is emptied, but are deleted after a set period by drupal_delete_file_if_stale(). This ensures that files referenced by a cached page will still be available.
>   
>   `drupal_delete_file_if_stale()` defaults to 30 days - so if a) Cron is running properly and b) you see aggregated files older than 30 days, you have a different problem.

`variable_get('drupal_stale_file_threshold', 2592000)` is the 30 day check.
`variable_set('drupal_stale_file_threshold', 172800)` would change the timeout to two days. On a site where cache handling is strictly controlled, the time could be even shorter.

Source: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_build_css_cache/7
See [`drupal_delete_file_if_stale()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_delete_file_if_stale/7) for more information.

- **Is there some reason both .css and .css.gz files are kept?**

> If CSS gzip compression is enabled, clean URLs are enabled (which means that rewrite rules are working) and the zlib extension is available then create a gzipped version of this file. This file is served conditionally to browsers that accept gzip using .htaccess rules.
>   
>   Source: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_build_css_cache/7 (In the function comments)

Also see [`drupal_build_js_cache()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_build_js_cache/7) which is nearly identical to `drupal_build_css_cache()`.

Comment: Thanks, I feel a bit lazy not having looked this up myself now ;)

Answer (score 0):

After 4 years, I have to disagree with the first answer, where the author states :

> "This ensures that files referenced by a cached page will still be available.".

Maybe certains things have been changed/optimized in the aggregation provisioning of older files, but if I delete an older file manually on the server at files/advagg_js (which I apparently still use in one of my browsers), the subsequent page reload is regenerating exactly the same file again with recently added javascript source code, as if `drupal_build_js_cache()` was executed on that aggregated file name.

eg. `js__22qMV1d_G25luSFBkuR7bIuKD5FE80eKuXx6ldibEixg__yjA2JTeF2f1LUJ3PMdjMr8k9nOPZQJIcvVw-c5Gz_yc__FY0NTHFBVMd9MIGE5srDXTejEZGP-ccSH7UX2zImN-0.js`

So I am concluding setting a significant lower `drupal_stale_file_threshold` would not cause any problems, and even deleting all aggregated files followed by a cache clear will force a regeneration of aggregates (tested and confirmed working on page reloads)

Answer (score -5):

- Get the Rules module
- Add a new rule that will be executed when the cron is running
- As an action select execute php code.
- Write the php code

Might be something like this:

```
$dir = 'your/directory/';
  foreach(glob($dir.'*.*') as $v){
  unlink($v);
}
```

These php functions might help you to modify the code as you like.

- Glob http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php
- unlink http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

**Be very careful before executing this! If not used right you may delete your site! Before trying this code test it on a localhost**