# Place CSS/JS aggregated files in a hierarchical directory structure

Tags: 7, files, css-js-aggregation

I use css and js aggregation for increase the speed of a drupal 7 website. Now, when I log in with user A, four news files (one css and one js) are added in the files website directory like that :

[image]

In linux, the profmances becomes bad when a folder contains too many files. So i'm looking for save these files in a hierarchical structure of directories, example :

directory_css_day0/mounth0/year0

-> contains somes css

directory_css_day1/mounth0/year0

-> contains somes css

...

directory_css_dayN/mounthN/yearN

-> contains somes css

How can I do that with Drupal mechanisms ?

Not the subjet of my [previous topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201721/css-js-aggregation-huge-number-of-files)

This previous post speaks about the number of files. Here, I'm looking for a way for manage the filesystem. I thought it was better to create another topic

Comment: Those files should be being cleared out on cron, so under normal circumstances this isn't something you need to worry about. Check that your cron jobs are running properly and try tuning the `drupal_stale_file_threshold` variable to something more appropriate for your usage

Comment: deleted in 30 day with default configuration. But, this website will manage a large number of user then a large number of files everyday. And if I shorten the time of removal, it means the page load time will become periodically longer. That's why I'm looking to save these files in a hierarchical structure of directories

Comment: Drupal doesn't have support for that so I think you'd be looking at hacking a bunch of core code to change it. Might be wrong though

Comment: Yes, I wait some time for another answer...but if there isn't 'drupal way', Ill use tidy solution (the cron time..)

Comment: You have already posted [CSS/JS aggregation, huge number of files](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201721/css-js-aggregation-huge-number-of-files) Please do not double post.

Comment: this previous post speaks about the number of files. Here, I'm looking for a way for manage the filesystem. I thought it was better to create another topic